# In AngularJs set a variable in forEach for each object

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to run a forEach function with data from a query and I want to set a variable for each object in that data to be able to use in a ng-repeat. I keep overriding the variable and cannot wrap my head around setting the variable for each one.

```
CategoryCardService.query({}, function (data) {
            $scope.categoryCards = data;
            angular.forEach(data, function (value) {
                var categoryOccupancyPercent = $filter('number')(value.occupancy_percent * 100, 0);
                var categoryTotalTurnover = value.total_turnover;

                var doughnut_chart_min = 0;
                var doughnut_chart_max = 0;

                doughnut_chart_min = categoryOccupancyPercent;
                doughnut_chart_max = 100 - categoryOccupancyPercent;

                data.doughnutData = [doughnut_chart_min, doughnut_chart_max];
                data.display = categoryOccupancyPercent + '%';

            });


        });
```

Comment: If you want each element of the data array to have a dougnutData field, what you need is `value.doughnutData = ...;`, not `data.doughnutData = ...`. The current element of the array is `value`. `data` is the whole array.

Answer (score 0):

Pass in the key and assign like that.

```
CategoryCardService.query({}, function (data) {
    $scope.categoryCards = data;
    angular.forEach(data, function (value, key) {
       // ...
       data[key].display = categoryOccupancyPercent + '%';
    });
});
```

Comment: Why not just `value.display = categoryOccupancyPercent + '%';` ?

Comment: Oops, oversight on my part. Main point is don't add a new key to the overall object.